# Is there any known relationship between $x, y$ the solution of $ax+by=n$ in integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It is well known that the equation $ax+by = n$ has a solution in integers $x$ and $y$ iff $gcd(a,b)|n$. I would like to know if there is a theorem in number theory to show that there is a relationship between $x$ and $y$. An example of such a relationship might be their being relatively prime or something similar to that.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are not unique. There are infinitely many solutions $x,y$ if $d\mid n$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479220/show-that-if-gcda-b-mid-c-then-the-equation-ax-by-c-has-infinitely).

Comment: I know that , but i seek for example if there is known theorem show the existence of relationship between those solutions

Comment: Converse of Bezout's Theorem, perhaps.

Comment: There's the obvious relationship that $y=(ax-n)/b$...

Comment: but this can't tel us any thing about the nature of the existed relationship between x, and y in the view of elementary number theory , check out the answer of :Dietrich Burde

Comment: you might be interested about Popovicius' Theorem, have a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204037v1)

Comment: Given $a, b, n$ fixed, there always is an explicit description of all the pairs $(x, y)$. See e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c).

Comment: Thanks for the slick link , i have to check it

Comment: @PavelČoupek, i don't know no vote neither question and neither answer and comments i don't know if it is a trivial question or no  interest of people for it !!!

Comment: the matter is that the solution to linear diophantine equations is an argument that has been dealt since .. Diophantus, and there is a vast literature about. So, unless you have a more specific question, there is no much to say, that you cannot find on the web.

Comment: I think i specified "An example of such a relationship might be their being relatively prime or something similar to that."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always there are solutions because if $(a,b)=d\gt 1$ then it is clear that $d$ must divide $n$. When there is a solution $(x_0,y_0)$ you have
$$\begin{cases}ax+by=n\\ax_0+by_0=n\end{cases}\Rightarrow a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=0\Rightarrow\begin{cases}x-x_0=bt\\y-y_0=at\end{cases}$$ which gives a parametrization of $x$ and $y$ in function of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

If $ax+by=d\mid n$ for $d=gcd(a,b)$, then we must have $gcd(x,y)=1$. So in this case the solutions $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/230997/prove-that-if-a-b-x-y-are-integers-with-ax-by-gcda-b-then-gcdx-y-1).

Comment: thanks a lot this what i feel and what i wrote in my question !!!

Comment: then we can deduce also gcd(x, y) |n

Comment: I have checked ur link but  in the linked question instead n he cited gcd(a,b) and the last is not necessary devides n

Comment: But $d=gcd(a,b)$  necessarily divides $n$. You have written it yourself in the question, because otherwise there is no solution $x,y$.

Comment: mayeb i can understanding it as this : if it has a solution then gcd(x,y)=1

Comment: Vote it's not important for me only to improve my  mathematical skill's

Answer (score 0):

Consider any pair $(x_0,y_0)$ and any pair $(a,b).$ Define $n=ax_0+by_0.$ We have that $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution of   $ax+by=n.$ Since the pair $(x_0,y_0)$ is arbitrary you can't expect any relation in general.

**Edit**

What we can say is that $gcd(x_0,y_0)|n.$ Why? Because the equation $x_0x+y_0y=n$ has solution: $(a,b).$

Comment: good , you did permutation to ur solutions 4m (x,y) to (a,b)